# Parsing years from strings

Tags: string, parsing, substring, vb.net-2010

I have 12-13 strings like

- FVS1012 **09** GO5
- OCGG **85** 0827KU9

where depending on length I have to get the **bold** part which means the year, in the example it would be 2009 and 1985.

How to get the "year"?

```
Dim str As String
Dim ResultStr As String
str = "FVS101209GO5"
Dim number As Integer = str.Length()
Select Case number
    Case 12
        ResultStr = str.Substring(8, 12)
        ResultStr = ResultStr.Substring(1, ResultStr.Length() )
    Case 13
        ResultStr = str.Substring(5, 13)
        ResultStr = ResultStr.Substring(1, ResultStr.Length() )
    Case Else
        Debug.WriteLine("other")
End Select
```

Is there any other better approach?

Comment: From the way the strings look, I don't see any pattern that you could easily identify except scanning for "a sequence of digits with no alphanumeric characters". Without knowing more about the format of the strings though, I doubt that this would result in a "better" solution, just a different one.

Comment: if the year always stands alone (and is the only one to do so) this regex would do it: `\b(\d{2})\b`

Comment: How would you implement it into the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably do it as.........

```
Select Case number
  Case 12
    ResultStr = mid(str, 8 ,2)
  Case 13
    ResultStr = mid(str, 5, 2)
  Case Else
    Debug.WriteLine("other")
End Select
```

Note that it only save one line per case statement so wether it is worth doing or not? i'm not sure